# Can i add image into div with classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add image into div, with classes, like when I click on `.img123(img class)` to be inserted into `.div123(div class)`.
With append, how many times I click on button that times is adding, I need only one time. And it's not with classes.

```
$("#theDiv").append("img id='theImg' src='theImg.png'/>");
```

Is there any function some like

```
('.img123').click(function() { 
     $('.img123'). adding image only one time into ('.div123');
});
```

Comment: First of all : append("<img id='theImg' src='theImg.png'/>"); You've missed the open '<'

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type. Try this:

```
$('.img123').one(function() {
    //enter code here
});
```